# Вывод в консоль графика ряда Фурье

Tags: c++, графика

Пытаюсь вывести в консоль график прямоугольной волны через синусоиды, но по какой-то причине во 2 и 4 координатных плоскостях амплитуда возрастает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include "Graphics+.h"
#include "Sphere.h"
int main()
    int heg = gr::GetHeg();
    Sleep(50);
    vector<Line> mas;
    vector<Pivot> pt;
    float R_,tipar=120;
    const int k=5;
    int tmp = 1;//увеличивается на 2 при добавлении в массив нового объекта
    Line l1(A, tipar * (4 / (tmp * 3.14)), RGB(255, 0, 0));
    mas.push_back(l1);
    //добавляем векторы в массив

    while (!_kbhit())
    {
        //поворот отрезка
        f = 1;
        for (int i = 0;i <= k;i++)
        {
            mas[i].LRotate(f);
            f += 2;
        }
        //рисуем
        gr::Line(gr::dcMem, mas[0].Start.x, mas[0].Start.y, mas[0].End.x, mas[0].End.y);
        for (int i = 0;i < k;i++)
        {
            mas[i + 1].SetStart(mas[i].End);
            gr::Set_pen(gr::dcMem, mas[i + 1].col, 3);
            gr::Line(gr::dcMem, mas[i + 1].Start.x, mas[i + 1].Start.y, mas[i + 1].End.x, mas[i + 1].End.y);
        }
        //горизонталь
        //точки
        //выводим из памяти
        //стираем
        //очистка точек
        Sleep(10);
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Sphere.h

```
class Line
{
private:
    float t = 0;
public:
    float R;
    POINT Start, End;
    COLORREF col;
    Line(POINT strt_, float R_, COLORREF col_)
    {
        col = col_;
        Start = strt_;
        R = R_;
        End.x = Start.x + R;
        End.y = Start.y;
    }
    Line(POINT strt_, float R_)
    {
        Start = strt_;
        R = R_;
        BYTE r, g, b;
        r = 50 + rand() % 200;
        g = 50 + rand() % 200;
        b = 50 + rand() % 200;
        col = RGB(r, g, b);
        End.x = Start.x + R;
        End.y = Start.y;
    }
    void LRotate(int fi)
    {
        End.x = Start.x + R * cos(t*fi);
        End.y = Start.y - R * sin(t*fi);
        t += 0.01;
    }
    void SetStart(POINT start_) {Start = start_;}
};

class Pivot
{
public:
    float x, y;
    Pivot(float x_, float y_) :x(x_), y(y_) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я ставил строку `mas[i + 1].SetStart(mas[i].End);`  уже после того как повернул все линии, а надо ставить до поворота отрезка

```
    //поворот отрезка
        f = 1;
        for (int i = 0;i <= k;i++)
        {
            mas[i].LRotate(f);      
            if (i == k) continue;
            else mas[i + 1].SetStart(mas[i].End);
            f += 2;
        }
```